Gamlss Monte Carlo Simulation
I'm having some problems with a Monte Carlo simulation. I want to estimate the parameters of the model, but the mean of the estimatives are not converging for the true values of the parameters, anyone knows how to fix that? 
require(gamlss.dist)
require(gamlss)
require(robustbetareg)

n_sim \<- 1000
n \<- 50

`## valores reais de Beta e Phi`
beta \<- c(1.13, -0.75, 0.40)
phi \<- 10

`# geração das amostras`
set.seed(497532)
cov1 \<- runif(n, 0, 1)
set.seed(4972533)
cov2 \<- rexp(n, 2)

mu \<- exp(beta\[1\] + beta\[2\] \* cov1 + beta\[3\] \* cov2) /
(1 + exp(beta\[1\] + beta\[2\] \* cov1 + beta\[3\] \* cov2))

simulation \<- function(numero_iteracoes) {
estimativas \<- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = n_sim, ncol = 3))
estimativas_robust \<- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = n_sim, ncol = 3))

colnames(estimativas) \<- c("coef_1", "coef_2", "coef_3")
colnames(estimativas_robust) \<- c("coef_1", "coef_2", "coef_3")

for (i in 1:n_sim) {
set.seed(4973 + i^2 + i)

    y <- try(rSIMPLEX(1, mu, phi), silent = TRUE)

    if (inherits(y, "try-error")) {
      warning(paste("Erro na geração de y na iteração", i))
      next  # Passa para a próxima iteração
    }

    if (length(y) == 0) {
      warning(paste("Vetor y vazio na iteração", i))
      next  # Passa para a próxima iteração
    }

    data_simulated <- data.frame(y = y, cov1 = cov1, cov2 = cov2)
    modelo <- gamlss(y ~ cov1 + cov2, data = data_simulated, family = SIMPLEX(), 
                 mu.link = "logit", control = gamlss.control(c.crit = 0.0001, n.cyc = 50))
    estimativas[i, ] <- coef(modelo)

    # modelo2 <- robustbetareg(y ~ cov1 + cov2, data = data_simulated, 
    # link = "logit", type = "LSMLE", robustbetareg.control(start = c(1, -0.5, 0.3)))
    # estimativas_robust[i, ] <- coef(modelo2)

    }
    return(estimativas)
 }

`First, I load the necessary packages: gamlss.dist, gamlss, and robustbetareg. These packages are used to fit generalized regression models using the Simplex distribution and for robust beta regression. I then set the simulation parameters with 1000 simulations (n_sim) and a sample size of 50 (n). I define the true values of the regression coefficients (beta) and the dispersion parameter (phi).
Next, I generate the covariates cov1 and cov2 using uniform and exponential distributions, respectively, and set seeds for reproducibility. The mean mu is calculated using the inverse logit function.
I define a simulation function that performs the simulations. It creates data frames to store the estimates from each iteration for both the regular and robust models. In each iteration, a new seed is set to ensure reproducibility. A response variable y is generated using the Simplex distribution. If y generation fails or produces an empty vector, the iteration is skipped. A gamlss model is then fitted using the generated data, and the coefficients are stored in the estimativas data frame.
However, I am encountering convergence issues with the parameters. Despite setting c.crit = 0.0001 and n.cyc = 50 in the gamlss.control function, the model often fails to converge properly. This results in some iterations being skipped and warnings being issued about convergence problems.
Finally, I run the simulation function and remove any rows with NA values from the results. I then display and summarize the results to analyze the estimates obtained from the simulations, but the convergence issues need to be addressed to improve the reliability of the estimates.
